# method missing when test helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I want to create a gem which can add some helper method to rails:

```
module SharpAssets
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "my_railtie.configure_rails_initialization" do |app|  
        app.middleware.use ::ActionDispatch::Static, "public"
        ActionView::Base.send :include, ViewHelpers

    end

    config.to_prepare do
      ActionView::Helpers.class_eval do
        #ActionView::Base.send :include, SharpAssets::ViewHelpers
      end
    end
  end

  module ViewHelpers
        #include Generators::Pagedown
        puts "initializer my_railtie.configure_rails_initialization"

        def sharp_assets
            "sharp_assets"
        end
    end
end
```

and my test case is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SharpAssetsTest < ActionView::TestCase

  test "pagedown_tag be html safe" do
    assert sharp_assets, ""
  end
end
```

and my test_helper is :

```
# Configure Rails Environment
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment.rb",  __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"

Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!

# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

# Load fixtures from the engine
if ActiveSupport::TestCase.method_defined?(:fixture_path=)
  ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = File.expand_path("../fixtures", __FILE__)
end
```

and my gem's directory is:

[image]

The error is

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `sharp_assets' for #<SharpAssetsTest:0x007ffe3c5abf08>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you required your lib in your test_helper.rb?

Comment: Does the test case will load dummy application and dummy application load my lib, so the test case load the lib ?

Comment: What does `require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment.rb",  __FILE__)` use for ?